# How to calculate median inside a nested select query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

UPDATE:
My real purpose is I want to calculate a median and 3 summations all in one query. So here is what I am trying to do after suggestion

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN i.code = 'T_186' THEN wf.value END) AS space_listed,
       SUM(ws.floor_space) as floor_space_available,
       SUM(ws.pallet) as pallet_space_available,
       AVG(t1.value) as floor_space_median
       FROM warehouses w JOIN
     warehouse_factors wf
     ON w.id = wf.warehouse_id  JOIN
     items i
     ON i.id = wf.item_id JOIN
     warehouse_spaces ws
     ON
    ws.warehouse_id=w.id LEFT JOIN
    (
SELECT wf.id, wf.value, @rownum:=@rownum+1 as `row_number`, @total_rows:=@rownum
  FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r , warehouses w
  JOIN warehouse_factors wf 
  ON w.id=wf.id 
  JOIN items i
  ON i.id=wf.item_id 
  WHERE wf.value is NOT NULL 
  AND
  i.code = 'T_032'
  ORDER BY wf.value
) as t1 
ON
t1.id = w.id

WHERE i.code IN ('T_041', 'T_186', 'T_032') AND
      w.city_id = 1 AND
      w.stage = 'live' AND
      w.warehouse_type = 'Warehouse services';
```

Please need help in this. I know I have to add

```
WHERE
t1.row_number IN ( FLOOR((@total_rows+1)/2), FLOOR((@total_rows+2)/2) );
```

but I can't figure how to incorporate this in the query.

Any other suggestion would be of great help

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions (not tested, they hopefully work):

**Use variables**

```
SET
    @p1 = NULL,
    @p2 = NULL;

-- assign result of your first query to @p1
SELECT
    @p1 := SUM(warehouse_factors.value)
FROM
    ...;

-- assign result of your second query to @p2
SELECT
    @p2 := warehouse_factors.value
FROM
    ...;

SELECT
    @p1 AS space_listed,
    @p2 AS pallet_median;
```

Or:

**Join both queries**

```
SELECT
    t1.space_listed,
    t3.pallet_median
FROM
    (
        -- your first query here
    ) AS t1
    FULL OUTER JOIN (
        -- your second query here
    ) AS t3 ON 1 = 1
```

Comment: Please I have updated my question upon some suggestion from below answer. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN i.code = 'T_186' THEN wf.value END) AS space_listed,
       SUM(CASE WHEN i.code = 'T_041' AND wf.value > 0 THEN wf.value END) AS pallet_median
FROM warehouses w JOIN
     warehouse_factors wf
     ON w.id = wf.warehouse_id LEFT JOIN
     items i
     ON i.id = wf.item_id
WHERE i.code IN ('T_041', 'T_186') AND
      w.city_id = 2 AND
      w.stage = 'live' AND
      w.warehouse_type = 'Warehouse services'
```

Comment: The second part is not the summation. It can result in more than one row. It is a selection. So I wanted the summation part(space_listed) with every other row of the another query(pallet_median)

Comment: I have updated my question and with your suggestion added somethings. Please need help in this.